# How to form a 3d array by spreading a 1d vector

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

A frequent task is to form an array that contains a variable raised to a combination of powers.  If p is the sequence 1,2,3 then I could want X^{p(k)+p(l)} for k,l=1,2,3  This MWE does just that:

```
Program Main
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
implicit none
integer(c_int) :: p(3)=(/0,1,0/)
integer(c_int) :: arrayP(3,3)
integer(c_int) :: krow,kcol
real(c_double) :: arrayR(3,3)
arrayP=spread(p,1,3)+spread(p,2,3)
do krow=1,3
   write(*,*)(arrayP(kcol,krow),kcol=1,3)
end do
arrayR=2.0d0**arrayP
! write array as three frames side by side
do krow=1,3
   write(*,fmt="(3(1pe10.2))")(arrayR(kcol,krow),kcol=1,3)
end do
End Program Main
```

The output is:

```
       0           1           0
       1           2           1
       0           1           0
1.00E+00  2.00E+00  1.00E+00
2.00E+00  4.00E+00  2.00E+00
1.00E+00  2.00E+00  1.00E+00
```

I need to extend this to a 3d array, in order to find X^{p(k)+p(l)}+p(m)} for k,l,m=1,2,3 The obvious extension of what I have in the MWE:

```
integer(c_int) :: arrayP(3,3,3)
arrayP=spread(p,1,3)+spread(p,2,3)+spread(p,3,3)
```

doesn't work, because you cant spread an array in more than n+1 dimensions, where n is the rank of p, in this case 1. Neither questions 21010295 or 31573252 address this issue. Suggestions?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Otherwise people won't see your question.

Comment: Have you considered `spread(spread(...))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain spread as mentioned by francescalus to obtain a 3D array (see below)
The 3 first writes produce all the sequence 1, 2 and 3.
However, you might consider to just 3 nested loop which is my opinion is easier to read.

```
program test_spread
  implicit none
  integer :: a(3) = (/ 1, 2, 3 /)
  integer :: array(3,3,3)
  real    :: arrayR(3,3,3)
  integer :: i,j,k

  array = spread(spread(a, 2, 3),3,3)
  write(6,*) array(:,1,1)

  array = spread(spread(a, 1, 3),3,3)
  write(6,*) array(1,:,1)

  array = spread(spread(a, 1, 3),2,3)
  write(6,*) array(1,1,:)

  arrayR = 2.0**(                           &
     spread(spread(a, 2, 3),3,3) +           &
     spread(spread(a, 1, 3),3,3) +           &
     spread(spread(a, 1, 3),2,3))

  write(6,*) 'arrayR (1)',arrayR
  do k = 1,3
    do j = 1,3
      do i = 1,3
        arrayR(i,j,k) = 2.0**(a(i)+a(j)+a(k))
      end do
    end do
  end do

  write(6,*) 'arrayR (2)',arrayR

 end program test_spread
```

Comment: @Alex338207  The reason for not using do loops is that the real version of this code is time critical.  Your suggestion (1) is just what I was looking for  Thanks to all

Comment: @high-performance-mark, thanks for the comment. `arrayR` should have been declared as real, indeed. I fixed my answer.

Comment: @ClintonWinant, note that vectorization is only beneficial in interpreted languages like matlab, octave, python/numpy, ... . In compiled language, like Fortran, vectorization can lead to unnecessary memory allocation and harm performance. But your case here, the "spreaded" arrays are still quite small, so this is probably not an issue here.